# Elementary Set Theory - Rigorous Proof Requested

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the following statement is incorrect:

$$ (A_1 - A_2) \space \cup A_2 = A_2 $$

However, I do not know how to show it rigorously.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to show a counter-example.
Let $A_{1}=\{a,b,c\}$ and $A_{2}=\{b\}$. Then $A_{1}-A_{2}=\{a,c\}$ and $(A_{1}-A_{2})\cup A_{2}=\{a,b,c\}=A_{1}\neq A_{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_2$ be any set and choose $A_1$ to be any nonempty set that is not a subset of $A_2$.

Then there must exist an $x \in A_1$ such that $x \not\in A_2$.

This $x$ is in $A_1 - A_2$ by definition and hence is in the union $(A_1 - A_2) \cup A_2$.

Thus $x$ is in the left hand side, but not the right. So the two sets cannot be equal.

In particular, choose $A_1 = \{a\}$ and $A_2 = \{\}$. Then

$$\begin{eqnarray}
(A_1 - A_2) \cup A_2     &=& A_1 \cup A_2    &=& A_1 \ni a\\
\bigl(\{a\} - \{\}\bigr) \cup \{\} &=& \{a\} \cup \{\} &=& \{a\} \ni a
\end{eqnarray}$$

but clearly $a \not\in \{\} = A_2$.

Comment: To disprove you need a solid counter example

Comment: Not necessarily. This is a general counterexample that shows exactly where the statement fails.

Comment: Yes, you need a solid counter-example. Counter-examples are concrete, not arbitrary.

Comment: Have you ever heard of proof by contradiction? Concreteness is not required for a disproof. I'll edit in a concrete demonstration though for you constructivists.

Comment: I'm talking about counter-examples, not methods demonstration. Further, you don't gave a proof by contradiction. Sorry, but you are wrong.

Comment: I would say that this is fine, but could be rephrased slightly to satisfy the naysayers.  Instead of beginning with "suppose..." you could begin by saying "As a counterexample take any $A_1,A_2$ such that $A_1\setminus A_2\neq \emptyset$."  It is common knowledge (*and otherwise incredibly trivial to show*) that such a choice of $A_1,A_2$ exist and is generally not worth anyone's time to prove explicitly.  Only in the cases where the premise is not common knowledge or where the premise has a chance of never being true is the extra effort *truly* required.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz. I've modified it slightly to seem less wishy-washy.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I understand you, but that old history: it's a matter of mathematics, not faith.

Answer (score 0):

To show that a statement is not true, you just need to show a counterexample. Here, lots of them will work, but an easy way to see it is to let $A_1$ be any nonempty set and let $A_2$ be the empty set.